# Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'discord' is not defined

Tags: python, discord.py

Soy nuevo utilizando **`discord.py`** hace poco cree un *bot* y he tenido algunos problemas que he podido resolver pero este en concreto no puedo resolverlo.

Este es el error que obtengo:

> File "C:\Users\gsz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
> raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'discord' is not defined

Este es el código que tengo por el momento:

```
  import os
    
    from discord.ext import commands
    
    from dotenv import load_dotenv
    
    import urllib.request
    
    import json
    
    import datetime
    
    
    load_dotenv()
    
    TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")
    
    bot=commands.Bot(command_prefix= "!") #prefijo del bot
    
    @bot.command()
    
    async def ping(ctx):
    
        await ctx.send("pong")
    
    @bot.command()
    
    async def info(ctx):
    
        embed= discord.Embed(title=f"{ctx.guild.name}", description="LOS COMANDOS SON: ", timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow(), color=discord.Color.blue())
    
        emb.add_field(name="server created at", value=f"{ctx.guild.created_at}")
    
        emb.add_field(name="server owner", value=f"{ctx.guild.owner}")
    
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    
    #evento
    
    @bot.event()
    
    async def on_ready():
    
        print("El tio Lucio está conectado")
    
    bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que veo, no estas importando *discord*, y estas usando ese objeto sin tenerlo definido.

Usa:

```
import discord
```

Comment: me sentí super tonto al releer el código tienes razón, muchas gracias